# drupal Select cck onchange handler

Tags: drupal, select, onchange

i'm adding onchange handler to all cck fields by following manner.

```
function bday_form_event_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  $form['title']['#attributes'] = array('onchange' => "titleval()");
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'bday_form_event_node_form_cck_alter';
}
function bday_form_event_node_form_cck_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['field_date1'][0]['value']['#attributes'] = array('onchange' => "dateval()"); //Text Field
 $form['field_city']['#attributes'] = array('onchange' => "cityval()"); //Select Field
}
```

But Onchange handler for **Select** is not added to the dom   .

Comment: Why add this in the html, and not use a .js file / jQuery instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a little on what googletorp said.

This is not the way to add behaviours to forms in drupal.

There is a very nice [JS api](http://drupal.org/node/205296) that comes with drupal which can aid you in doing this.

Roughly what you would want is something like this.

```
Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = function(context) {
  $('.title').change(function() {titleval() }) ;
  $('.field_date1').change(function() {dateval()});
  $('.field_city').change(function() {cityval()});
}
```